# Compose and pipe a gzipped tar archive in one go

Tags: shell-script, files, tar

I'm trying to come up with an effective way to create a gzipped archive of various system partitions on Android, piping everything out to stdout so as to be able to encrypt it as it comes across via `gpg`.

The workflow looks like this:

```
adb shell "/data/dobackup.sh" | gpg --output suchbackup.tar.gz.gpg --encrypt --sign --recipient me@myemail.com
```

The shell script needs to basically do this:

```
cat /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/recovery > recovery.img
cat /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system > system.img
...
```

However, as seen, I'd like to do this whole thing over an adb shell execution so that everything is transferred over USB, into memory, and quickly is encrypted then written to disk, ie leaving no unencrypted trace.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how to manufacture the internals of the script into a tar.gz file composed of multiple files/sources. Basically, I'm looking to output a tar.gz file from stdout from this script which includes the following files inside:

```
/recovery.img
/system.img
/userdata.img
/cache.img
/...
```

Is there any way I can do this? I haven't encountered a problem like this in my travels so far.

Comment: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-tar/2010-01/msg00001.html

Comment: Rather than dump to `.img` files can you archive those paths directly?

Comment: What Linux tools are available on the Android system? There's a world of difference between Gingerbread standard, ICS standard, or having a full BusyBox.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that you want to use tar to create an archive and send it to standard out, that's what happens by default if you don't use the `f` option to send the output to a file:

```
tar cz /{recovery,system,userdata,cache}.img | ...
```

If the problem is archiving "files" which don't actually exist on the filesystem, that's a bit trickier because of the format of tar files: each file is *preceded* by a header which includes the filesize. The filesize in the header must be correct because that's the only way that `tar` has to know where the next header entry starts.

So it's only feasible to do this if you can predict precisely the size of the generated file object. If you can do that,you should be able to construct a tar file using, for example, the standard python library [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) module.

Comment: I know how to put a tar to stdout, it's just how to compose the contents of the tar, as they're basically dumps of filesystems that need to be generated from dd or cat and never saved to disk.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Ah. That's trickier because the tar header includes the size of the file, so you'd have to know how big the filesystem dump was before you generated it. If you know that, you can use something like the python `tarfile` module.

Comment: Hmm, that's a bummer. I might just have to do them one at a time, encrypt them separately, and then pack them all in a tar, but then I'd lose compression, maybe I'll wrap them in gzip first...

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay: If the individual files are large enough, you might as well compress them first and then archive the compressed files. That lets you extract (or replace) an individual compressed file. Archiving and then compressing is a big win for an archive of lots of little files, but it doesn't save much for an archive of a few enormous files.

Answer (score 0):

A thread you may wish to checkout on [Hak5](https://forums.hak5.org/index.php?/topic/39421-gnupg-tools-for-unattended-encryption/) forums will show the way to a project being worked on that makes use of `mkfifo` & other Bash magics... I've found that once set up it makes for easy encryption of nearly anything and there's tools for bulk decryption.

Prof is in the pudding so [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/S0AndS0/Perinoid_Pipes) is currently used to show all working features including the recovery of test strings, file, and directory. This has been tested on Android with Busybox and chroot Linux, but you may only need busybox (if output rotation to email is disabled) because most of the source code is designed around limited systems.

Hint for `tar` specifically, check the build logs from the past few days and you'll find that it can be a *hair-pulling* experience if ya forget to put the trailing `-` or mess with `v` for testing.